# How to change default format of Excel which apply to all new Excels Workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, templates, default-settings

Basically There are two settings which I want to change from default behaviour of Excel.

1. **Changing Default Column width**

In Excel, Currently default column width is set to "8.43" for every new instance of Excel.

I need to change this setting and I want to change it once and it should be applied to all new Excels afterwards.

2. **To stop excel to convert large numbers into exponent number**

If it is possible to set a general rule in excel which suggests all excel instance not to convert large numbers into exponent value.

**update - Here I would like excel to accept data as it is entered by user (and not format at all)**

---

For first requirement I have created a template `Book.xltx` where I have set `default Width` to 20 and save this template into

C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART

path. But this doesn't seem to help.

---

**UPDATE**

I Found the solution for the first question [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/1001660-book-xltx-xlstart-template-settings-not-being-used-excel.html)

> I was able to resolve this by disabling the Start screen in Excel.
>
> I had the exact same problem. You all previous posters didn't clarify
>   whether your Sheet.xltx file was working - mine was working fine. I'd
>   open a new workbook & it would be the dumb default, but if I added a
>   sheet it would be my lovely default sheet.
>
> The problem was the same whether I picked "blank workbook" from the
>   start screen or just hit ctrl-N at any time.
>
> However, by going to File->Options
>
> Then General->Start up options-> uncheck "Show the Start screen when
>   this application starts"
>
> And now it's using my lovely template.

**But this is not working when I open CSV files in excel** how to enable it for CSVs as well.

Answer (score 0):

**To change Default Column Width, and Stop excel to convert large numbers into Exponential number on a WORKBOOK, I would like to suggest this VBA (Macro) code.**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    With ws

        .Cells.ColumnWidth = 20
        .Cells.NumberFormat = "0"
    End With
Next ws

End Sub
```

**How it works:**

- Press **ALT+F11** to open VB editor window.
- On Top Left find **Project Explorer,** Click on 
  **ThisWorkbook**.
- **Copy** & **Paste** this code.
- To see the effects `Close and Open` the 
  `Workbook`.

**N.B.**

- Every time you insert New Sheet, just `Close & Open` the `Workbook` to get the effect.

**Edited:**

*You may use this code on `Columns/Range` of your choice for specific Formats.*

```
Sub formatColumns()

     Columns(1).NumberFormat = "@"
     Columns(2).NumberFormat = "General"
     Columns(3).NumberFormat = "0"
     Columns(4).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
     Columns(5).ColumnWidth = 35
     Columns(6).RowHeight = 20

   End Sub

Or

Sheet1.Range("A2:E500").NumberFormat ="DD/MM/YYYY"



Sheet1.Range("A:E").NumberFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
```

Comment: what will it do, when excel is having data like "11.8" ?

Comment: @Amit,, it's a general solution, you asked how to stop Excel to convert Exponential conversion and I've suggested. Now you are thinking differently, next you say how about DATE. First you decide what is your real need!!

Comment: hello  Rajesh, I have updated my question. "Here I would like excel to accept data as it is entered by user (and not format at all)" Because preventing large data to be converted into exponent value, I cannot afford 11.8 to be converted into 12 .

Comment: @Amit,, this works in general for entire Sheet,, If You want handle both Exponentials and Numbers use this `.Cells.NumberFormat = "0#.0" `

Comment: I'm really sorry but that too will not fit into ""Here I would like excel to accept data as it is entered by user (and not format at all)"  .. "0#.0" will affect dates.

Comment: @Amit,, or apply different Cell Formats to specific Range like A:D for Exponentials E:G for Date and so on

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90429/discussion-between-rajesh-s-and-amit).